# From a non-native's standpoint: Which dictionary should I pay attention to when I find semantically contradictory definitions of a word?

Tags: dictionaries

[The following is one of dozens of cases I come across on a daily basis]

By accident, I have recently noticed that the phrasal verb **go through** (as in **experience**) -- which I've been using so far in my IELTS writing essays -- is associated with a connotation of *negativeness* (suffering, unpleasantness, etc). Flipping through dictionary pages I'm finding out they do not agree with one another over the level of negativity. Some have dismissed the negativity component very lightly, while others have *fundamentally*/*thoroughly* attached it to that concept. Others, though, have used parentheses. (Making a good decision in such case takes on added importance when I have, for instance, used **go through** in my essay, and after questioning its correctness I have ended up paging through dictionaries.)

To clarify, here's where I'm finding myself locked in:

> *Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary [11th]:* go through: 2.EXPERIENCE; UNDERGO.
>
> *The American Heritage Dictionary (5th)*:2. go through: To experience; Undergo
>
> **The online ones:**
>
> *Collins English Dictionary*: 4. (preposition) to suffer    [end of story?!]
>
> *oxford dictionaries:* Undergo (a difficult period or experience)
>
> the free dictionary: 2. To experience
>
> McMillan dictionary: 3. [TRANSITIVE] go through something:
>   to experience something difficult or unpleasant

I cannot reasonably take the most comprehensive meaning (maybe the Amr. Hert. Dict & Oxf. Dict.s, in the case on hand) all the time, under the assumption that the others have left something out, because a lengthy definition isn't necessarily the best one. Using only **one** **perfect dictionary**? There is no such dictionary out there, or else the **need** to set up brilliant communities like this would have never made itself felt. Come here and ask? I guess this has to be the best answer, but the need is too frequent and it takes me a long time. Googling? Yes, that works in some cases. But It's not reliable enough, I think, since you can't tell if the writer was a native speaker. Plus the fact that not *each and every* *composition/collocation* of words exists there, whereas the Googled term IS actually true (I say this out of a couple of such experiences).

Questions:

Q 1. What should I do (if anything at all!)?

Q 2. What does *go through* really mean? In other words, should I use it only when  something unpleasant/bad/difficult is involved?

Q 3. Are the editors of the community erasing thanks?

Comment: We don’t say tens of cases in English; we say dozens.

Comment: May be better on *meta* ?

Comment: @Erikkowal ; Thanks for extensive edit. I dared, albeit not to comply with two of them or three. Thank you once again.

Comment: Dictionaries do not define well. They miss so much: all the aspects of the word, all the contexts it could appear in, all the nuances, all the connotations, the social appropriateness.

Comment: For neutral (or even positive) examples: _go through puberty/menopause/changes/a reorganisation/a transformation/therapy/treatment/a procedure/recovery_.

Comment: I have to give *Merriam-Webster* an **F** for this definition. If you look at the context, it's actually a definition of the phrasal verb *go through with*.

Comment: @PeterShor ; edited! exactly. Here is the example that follows the definition:<I was going through with it, if it killed me. A. W. Long>.I'm new with the dictionary. It has its own logic in disposing phrasal verbs and brings them in independent entries from the main verb but just sometimes! I haven't learnt the logic yet. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever two dictionaries disagree about anything, I think you should consider both.

Words often have different connotations, depending on the experiences and perspective of the person reading / hearing the words.

When you see two dictionaries that disagree about the definition or connotation of a word, that is an indication to you that the word may have different connotations to different people.

At some point, you might intend to say one thing, and have the person receiving the message come away with something else altogether.

In the case of this particular phrase, "go through" or "get through" I think it can be used with varying degrees of negative connotation, but it is sometimes used in a positive or neutral connotation by the people I interact with daily as a native American English speaker in the northeast United States.

A neutral example would be, "I'm just going to go through the answers one more time before I turn in my test." Or, "Once you go through the tunnel, take the next left."

Comment: Unless I say, "I'm just going to go through the answers one more time before I turn in my test." Or, "Once you go through the tunnel, take the next left."

Comment: @Jim Thank you for your comment.  You are absolutely correct.  I hope you don't mind if I update my answer to include your examples.

Comment: Are you sure you're not exaggerating the extent of the negative connotations? I can think of a variety of other neutral examples: "A caterpillar goes through many physiological changes in the process of turning into the adult butterfly". "We went through [= consumed, used up] a whole case of wine last night". "The fax went through on the first attempt". "Let's go through the script of the play and analyse  the action from Ophelia's point of view".

Comment: I would suggest that the example "go through the tunnel" is not relevant here- although the words are the same the meaning is entirely different, meaning "to proceed through" - when navigating a tunnel the only way is "through"... That is not the same as experiencing something with some degree of negative connotation. In my opinion the degress of negativity associated with "go through" is set by the context, not the actual verb.

Comment: @Lumberjack ; Right. But As for "going through the answers" it seems to be mentioned independently of the current sense, in some dictionaries, and is said to mean "revise/review/examine". I think they are right, since it doesn't bear on "experiencing something".

Comment: @MarvMills- You are correct in that when used to mean "to endure a set of conditions" it can only have that meaning- it's tautological.  The point is, that there are other definitions as well, and thus blanket statements about the words "go through" cannot be made because they likely only apply to a subset of the possible definitions.

Comment: The advice about considering both definitions to be correct for some people, and mentioning the sender and receiver of the message, are spot on. -- I would put it this way: As the sender of a message (e.g. writer of a text), make sure to only use a word if it's appropriate according to all dictionaries. As the receiver (e.g. reader), be prepared that the intended meaning might be one that fits only one of the dictionaries.